# New column as function result in pandas dataframe of python

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas

I am very new to Python. I have a table in which I created a new column called "diff_gold" which is defined as follows:

```
df['diff_gold'] = (df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1'])
```

where 'Gold' and 'Gold.1' are existing columns in my table.

The result of the function should be

```
df['diff_gold'].argmax()
```

However, this does not work as a function:

```
def answer_two():

  df['diff_gold'] = df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']

  return df['diff_gold'].argmax()
  answer_two()
```

Could you please help me? How should I alter my code so that answer_two() returns the appropriate string value?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: it should be `idxmax` in pandas

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it still does not work when using idmax instead of argmax. :-(

Comment: In which way does that not work as a function? Also note two things. 1. You do not have any argument in your function. You may want to have the first line to be def answer_two(df). Also you indented the last line, so answer_two() is in your function (but will never be executed, as it is after a return command).

Comment: Also it would help if you could give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question. I just needed to change the intendation of the last line, as Fabian recommended:

```
def answer_two():

  df['diff_gold'] = (df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1'])

  return df['diff_gold'].argmax()
answer_two()
```